# How do I add cases to the switch statement for this terminal emulator codepen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codepen, terminal-emulator

I am editing the script of this codepen: https://codepen.io/rafael-casachi/pen/qLEeJV
to use on my website, but I can’t figure out how to add more cases to the switch statement that will perform the functions I need.  Here’s what I would like to add:

case ‘cd’
the user can type ‘cd’ followed by a word, then go to the page of my website with that path name (e.g. user types ‘cd shop’ and it opens a window with the url [www.mywebsite.com/shop](http://www.mywebsite.com/shop))

case ‘find’
the user can type ‘find’ followed by a word to search for that keyword on my website (like a search bar; e.g. the user types ‘find pants’ which triggers a search for anything with the keyword ‘pants’ on my website)

Any idea what I should do?  Thanks!

```
<script>

var util = util || {};
util.toArray = function(list) {
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
};

var Terminal = Terminal || function(cmdLineContainer, outputContainer) {
   window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

   var cmdLine_ = document.querySelector(cmdLineContainer);
   var output_ = document.querySelector(outputContainer);

   const CMDS_ = [
      'cat', 'clear', 'date', 'echo', 'help', 'uname', 'whoami', 'me'
   ];

   var fs_ = null;
   var cwd_ = null;
   var history_ = [];
   var histpos_ = 0;
   var histtemp_ = 0;

   window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      cmdLine_.focus();
   }, false);
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
   <output></output>
   <div id="input-line" class="input-line">
      <div class="prompt"></div><div><input class="cmdline" autofocus /></div>
   </div>
</div>

}

.ls-files {
   height: 45px;
   -webkit-column-width: 100px;
   -moz-column-width: 100px;
   -o-column-width: 100px;
   column-width: 100px;
}

<style>
$font-color: #0f8;
$bg-color: #111;
$header-color: #fff;
$selection-color: #FF5E99;
$font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
$font-size: 13px;

::selection {
  background: $selection-color;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
   font-family: $font-family;
   color: $header-color;
   background: $bg-color;
   font-size: $font-size;
}

#wrapper {
   padding: .1em 5em 1em 1em;
   line-height: 1;
   
   output {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      
      h3, h2 {
         margin: 0;
      }
      
      pre {
         margin: 0;
      }
      
      p {
         margin-top: .5em;
         margin-bottom: .5em;
      }
   }
}

.input-line {
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
</style>
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you'd add the commands to `CMDS_` variable and update the `execCMD` function to handle those additional commands. As for the specific capabilities you want to add, you'll have to figure something out yourself and then come back if you have specific issues you've tried and failed to resolve.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks I’ll try to figure that out—I just started learning jquery so I’m still pretty confused about how to work with the syntax. Any other tips you could provide would be greatly appreciated.